# Object Detection inference using multi-gpu & multi threading, Pytorch

Tags: python, multithreading, pytorch, object-detection, multi-gpu

I am trying to detect objects in a video using multiple GPUs. I want to distribute frames to GPUs for inference to increase total process time. I succeeded running inference in single gpu, but failed to run on multiple GPUs.

I thought dividing frames per number of gpus and processing inference would decrease the time. If there is another way I can decrease running time, I would be glad to receive suggestions.

I am using pre-trained model provided by Pytorch. What I tried is as follows:
1. I read the video and divide frames by number of gpus I have(currently two NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti)
2. Then, I distributed frames to gpus and process object detection inference. 
(Later I planned to use multi-threads to dynamically distribute frames per number of gpus, but currently I made it static)

The same method I tried worked well in Tensorflow using `with tf.device()` and I am trying to make it possible in Pytorch as well.

### pytorch_multithread.py

```
...
    def detection_gpu(frame_list, device_name, device, detect, model):
        model.to(device)
        model.eval()

        for frame in frame_list:
            start = time.time()
            detect.bounding_box_rcnn(frame, model=model)
            end = time.time()

            cv2.putText(frame, '{:.2f}ms'.format((end - start) * 1000), (40, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,
                        (255, 0, 0),
                        2)

            cv2.imshow(str(device_name), frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break


    def main():
        args = arg_parse()

        VIDEO_PATH = args.video

        print("Loading network.....")
        model = models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
        print("Network successfully loaded")

        num_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
        if torch.cuda.is_available() and num_gpus > 1:
            device = ["cuda:{}".format(i) for i in range(num_gpus)]
        elif num_gpus == 1:
            device = "cuda"
        else:
            device = "cpu"
        # class names ex) person, car, truck, and etc.
        PATH_TO_LABELS = "labels/mscoco_labels.names"

        # load detection class, default confidence threshold is 0.5
        if num_gpus>1:
            detect = [DetectBoxes(PATH_TO_LABELS, device[i], conf_threshold=args.confidence) for i in range(num_gpus)]
        else:
            detect = [DetectBoxes(PATH_TO_LABELS, device, conf_threshold=args.confidence) for i in range(1)]

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATH)

        # find number of gpus that is available
        frame_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

        # TODO: CPU환경 고려하기
        # divide frames of video by number of gpus
        div = frame_length // num_gpus
        divide_point = [i for i in range(frame_length) if i != 0 and i % div == 0]
        divide_point.pop()

        frame_list = []
        fragments = []
        count = 0
        while cap.isOpened():
            hasFrame, frame = cap.read()
            if not hasFrame:
                frame_list.append(fragments)
                break
            if count in divide_point:
                frame_list.append(fragments)
                fragments = []
            fragments.append(frame)
            count += 1
        cap.release()


        detection_gpu(frame_list[0], 0, device[0], detect[0], model)
        detection_gpu(frame_list[1], 1, device[1], detect[1], model)
        # Process object detection using threading
        # thread_detection = [ThreadWithReturnValue(target=detection_gpu,
        #                                           args=(frame_list[i], i, detect, model))
        #                     for i in range(num_gpus)]
        #
        #
        # final_list = []
        # # Begin operating threads
        # for th in thread_detection:
        #     th.start()
        #
        # # Once tasks are completed get return value (frames) and put to new list
        # for th in thread_detection:
        #     final_list.extend(th.join())
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### detection_boxes_pytorch.py

```
    def bounding_box_rcnn(self, frame, model):
            print(self.device)
            # Image is converted to image Tensor
            transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
            img = transform(frame).to(self.device)
            with torch.no_grad():
                # The image is passed through model to get predictions
                pred = model([img])

            # classes, bounding boxes, confidence scores are gained
            # only classes and bounding boxes > confThershold are passed to draw_boxes
            pred_class = [self.classes[i] for i in list(pred[0]['labels'].cpu().clone().numpy())]
            pred_boxes = [[(i[0], i[1]), (i[2], i[3])] for i in list(pred[0]['boxes'].detach().cpu().clone().numpy())]
            pred_score = list(pred[0]['scores'].detach().cpu().clone().numpy())
            pred_t = [pred_score.index(x) for x in pred_score if x > self.confThreshold][-1]
            pred_colors = [i for i in list(pred[0]['labels'].cpu().clone().numpy())]
            pred_boxes = pred_boxes[:pred_t + 1]
            pred_class = pred_class[:pred_t + 1]

            for i in range(len(pred_boxes)):
                left = int(pred_boxes[i][0][0])
                top = int(pred_boxes[i][0][1])
                right = int(pred_boxes[i][1][0])
                bottom = int(pred_boxes[i][1][1])

                color = STANDARD_COLORS[pred_colors[i] % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]

                self.draw_boxes(frame, pred_class[i], pred_score[i], left, top, right, bottom, color)
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Object_Detection_Video_AllInOne/pytorch_multithread.py", line 133, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Object_Detection_Video_AllInOne/pytorch_multithread.py", line 113, in main
        detection_gpu(frame_list[1], 1, device[1], detect[1], model)
      File "C:/Users/username/Desktop/Object_Detection_Video_AllInOne/pytorch_multithread.py", line 39, in detection_gpu
        detect.bounding_box_rcnn(frame, model=model)
      File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Object_Detection_Video_AllInOne\p_utils\detection_boxes_pytorch.py", line 64, in bounding_box_rcnn
        pred = model([img])
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection\generalized_rcnn.py", line 51, in forward
        proposals, proposal_losses = self.rpn(images, features, targets)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection\rpn.py", line 409, in forward
        proposals = self.box_coder.decode(pred_bbox_deltas.detach(), anchors)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection\_utils.py", line 168, in decode
        rel_codes.reshape(sum(boxes_per_image), -1), concat_boxes
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection\_utils.py", line 199, in decode_single
        pred_ctr_x = dx * widths[:, None] + ctr_x[:, None]
    RuntimeError: binary_op(): expected both inputs to be on same device, but input a is on cuda:1 and input b is on cuda:0
```

Comment: I am currently having the same issue. Should this be a problem of duplicating (or copying) model on each gpu? Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Pytorch provides DataParallel module to run a model on mutiple GPUs. Detailed documentation of DataParallel and toy example can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) and [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html).

Comment: Thank you, I have already seen those examples. But, examples were few and could not cover my question....